# How do I move a file based Tortoise SVN repository to a HTTP based repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a number of SVN repositories created by and accessed by the Tortoise SVN client using file:// access over a network path. I would like to be able to access these existings repositories using http://. I don't know if its possible to change it on an existing repository, or whether it needs to be copied into a new repository.

Either way if someone could outline the simplest way to accomplish this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/),
2. Put your repositories to `C:\Repositories\` or set VisualSVN Server to work with repos stored on a network share.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're right now accessing files via the `file://` protocol? Not a good idea with a shared repository. Especially if these are on network drives and not your local machine.

First, a clarification:

There are two different Subversion programs here:
 * Client
 * Server

TortoiseSVN is a ***client*_** program. You can use it to access a Subversion repository no matter what type of SUbversion server is being used. Saying "How do I move a file based TortoiseSVN repository" is confusing the client program (TortoiseSVN) with the server protocol. You can use TortoiseSVN once you move the file.

Now, getting to the Server...

There are three Server protocols Subversion can use:

- `file:///`: Not recommended for standard use, and definitely should not be used for shared or remote repositories. The `file://` protocol is useful because it's fast. Many Subversion web browsing platforms such as Fisheye or ViewVC use it.
- `svn://`: This uses the `svnserve` server. It's fast and simple to use. It's fine to use with multiple user access and is easy to setup. Directions for setting it up as a [Windows Service](http://subversion.open.collab.net/articles/svnserve-service.htm) abound. The main issue tends to be whether your network blocks port 3690 or not. Plus, security tends to be less flexible. For example, I like using the Windows Active Directory for security, and `svnserve` doesn't provide that easily. Security setup is simple (it's just a text file that's easily understandable), but someone has to maintain it.
- `http://`: This uses the Apache server via a Subversion plugin module. It's tricky to setup, but it's the most flexible. Plus, since it is usually off port 80, it is usually not blocked by a router. Fortunately, there are many *packages* out there that include Subversion configured with Apache for Windows

I would recommend that you try `svnserve` first and get that working. You don't have to install another program, and it's the easiest to get going.  It might be all you really need.

Once you get that working, you can try using one of the Apache based packages. I recommend CollabNet Edge. It allows you to do things such as use your Windows Active Directory for security without paying extra for it. (Which is the real reason to use Apache).

Comment: uberSVN allows you to use Active Directory for auth too.

Comment: @MandBeckett If it's like VisualSVN, the basic Apache/Subversion package is free, but you have to pay to get extras like ActiveDirectory integration.

Comment: Cheers, I've updated the question to reflect the hopefully now accurate repository server/client situation. Interesting you say that file:// is fast, but in my case its the slowest option - something to do with it being over a VPN. This is the main reason I need to change - speed. Will let you know how I get on.

Comment: @DavidW. - you get basic LDAP auth for free in uberSVN. Access Control is the paid add-on for more rigorous rules and auditing. Anyway, that's kind of outside this question so I'll shush now :)

Comment: @DaleBurrell `file://` can be slow over remote access, and you should never use `file://` over a network. However, if you're writing something like ViewVC, and you insist this program must be run locally to the repository, the `file://` protocol is the fastest and lightest weight.

Comment: While good information, it doesn't actually answer the question of "How to migrate a local TortoiseSVN 'File://' repo to a remote server based svn instance".

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this:

- using a GUI like [uberSVN](http://www.wandisco.com/ubersvn), VisualSVN Server or Collabnet Edge. These products take the headache away and give you the quickest and easiest way to achieve your goal, and they're free to download and install (VisualSVN Server and Edge have paid-Enterprise versions too).
- use a hosted solution such as Assembla or Beanstalk. These can be useful for getting started quickly, but beware of memory limits or additional costs.
- you could install Apache HTTP Server yourself and set it up to serve the repositories - instructions in the excellent SVNBook (Version Control with Subversion) book [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html). Probably the most difficult but gives you ultimate control and you learn how it's actually done in the meantime. :)

Comment: Useful information, although my question is specifically how to move/access an existing repository that is accessed using file:// to http://

Comment: most of the above will let you just add your existing repository in once you're setup, giving you http:// access pretty much immediately.